# Randomizing list elements (shuffle) in Java

Tags: java, random

I am writing a program which requires me in part to shuffle a list of elements using a predefined function for generating randomness to supply to the shuffler. The random function returns a float between [0,1) to the shuffling function and the shuffler then uses this randomness to decide which elements should go where in the list.

here is a sample list of elements I used to experiment with:

{"objectify", "simplify", "reduce", "reuse", "establish",
"rhetoric", "bastion", "smile", "dash", "relocate",
"embellishment", "dapple", "dot", "rewiring", "schooner"}

My question is, what is a good method for sorting these considering I may have a much, much larger pool of elements to rearrange?

Comment: [`Collections.shuffle(List<?>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class for shuffling and sort the elements:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

class ShuffleAndSort<T>
{
  List<T> list;
  public Shuffle(List<T> list)
  {
    this.list = list;
  }

  // Fisher–Yates shuffle
  public void shuffleArray(List<T> list)
  {
    Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      int index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
      // Simple swap
      T a = list.get(index);
      list.set(index, list.get(i));
      list.set(i, a);
    }
  }
  public boolean isInOrder(){
      //... to implement
  }
}
```

For sorting the Bogosort contemplate to shuffle until the list will be sort:

```
while(!isInOrder(list))
    myShuffle.shuffle(list);
```

### N.B.

I suggest use ArrayList